# page renders before DELETE request is done

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, httprequest

I'm working on a "todo app" Backbone client side. After I make a delete request in TodoView, it will be redirected to the index page(showing the whole list). **The problem is** that after redirecting, the deleted todo is still in the list. However it disappears after refreshing.

**Is it because** the todo list renders faster than the DELETE request being done?

In the todoView I listen to the 'delete' button:

```
events: {
  'click .red-button' : 'delete',
},

delete: function() {
  this.model.destroy({
    success: function(model, res) {
      $('.body-container').empty();
      //redirecting to the index page--the todo list
      navigate(''); //equals to Backbone.Router.prototype.navigate(url, {trigger: true}) 
    }
  })
},
```

I overrode sync for todo model. The 'delete' method is like:

```
case 'delete':
  request
    .del(this.url())
    .end(function(res) {
      console.log('deleting......');
    });
    options.success();
break;
```

Comment: Is the Todo collection listening for changes?

Comment: @steveax No... That might be why. How do I listen from collection? `collection.on('add', this.addOne);` in CollectionView and write a `addOne` function?

Comment: @stevax The `CollectionView` (or whatever View is responsible for displaying the collection) NOT the `collection` should be the one listening for changes. The collection doesn't need to "do" anything if one of it's models is destroyed. It's automatic.

Comment: In fact when model is destroyed the collection's listening and runs it's own stuff ;) https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L973

Comment: @AnatoliyZaslavskiy yes, sorry, meant the collection view.

Comment: @steveax in that case yup that's super important. In fact I would take a look at Marionette's CollectionView source for ideas on efficient ways to listen (not you gotta implement something similar): https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.collectionview.js#L72

Comment: The easiest (but least efficient) way is actually is to do `this.listenTo(collection, 'all', this.render)` and have the view `render` on ANY event. Note as your app gets slow you want to start implementing optimizations similar to Marionette's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use the `success` callback! Very bad practice/it's a bad habit to get into for the future (see below for "why"). Backbone isn't "done" doing it's thing until it fires a `destroy` event. So listen to the model's destroy event. Cleaner are easier :)

```
delete: function(){
  this.model.destroy();
  //Ideally put this in your ROUTER
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', function(){
     navigate();
  }
}
```

However you're not done there. The most likely problem you have is that whatever list view is on the index page isn't listening to it's models' `destroy` events. Assuming you used ItemViews (individual Views) you would do

```
 var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(){
     this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
   }
 });
```

That will fix the surface issue.

But in that case, you have a bigger underlying problem. Your ToDoList View from index page isn't properly getting removed when you navigate away. This causes a LOT of problems (especially once your application grows). Whenever a navigate event happens make sure ALL VIEWS are `remove()`d from the page. Very important!!!

If you post the code for your "index page" I can help you diagnose further.

**WHY USING `success` callback is bad (Draft 1)**

When you start building "real" applications on backbone generally there will be a LOT of views, models, and various objects "listening" for your model to be destroyed. You may have 5-10 different views listening to this model (in fact I've run into this situation in just about every enterprise app I've written). If you use the `success` callback, it becomes very confusing to track the chain of events that are happening. When an action (such as navigating away) happens they first (and only) place you want to look is the router. Otherwise, imagine there are 50-100 different "actions" that will cause a navigate to be fired, and they are all happening from the `success` callbacks of different models it will take you DAYS to track down why a certain navigate happened. If you let the object taking the action `listenTo` different objects, you have it centralized. I will explain this in a lot more detail later on (I know it seems confusing). But trust me on this one, you want to get away from using `success`.

Comment: Why do you think it's "Very bad practice" to use a `success` callback?

Comment: @fbynite I added a little explanation above. I'm gonna work on a better example why...To summarize, it works fine when you have a simple app, but when there's a LOT going on (I have built applications with ~300 JS files on Backbone) you get into a huge amount of debugging problems. Same reason why when you make a small application with jQuery and just start scattering various dom manipulations and listeners everywhere, it works. But when it gets more complicated, debugging's a b****

Comment: By the way @fbynite please ask more questions like "why is x bad practice". My goal is to start writing articles about what best practices are, why certain best practices exist, and how to actually implement those best practices.

Comment: @AnatoliyZaslavskiy While a noble task, questions asking about good/bad practices are more often than not off topic for Stackoverflow. You could always create a CW thread, however

Comment: Also @Jiayang just to help the community can you post your final code so that others can see the "right" way to do it?